# Responsive Images in Grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bulma, responsive-images

I'm using the [Bulma](https://bulma.io) grid framework to customize part of the interface for our Learning Management System. I have a simple vertical nav (1 column on larger screens) on the left and then there is a large promo banner in the middle (8 columns wide on larger screens) with a smaller promo banner to the right (3 columns wide on larger screens). I have it setup so that all three items show on desktop-sized screens, and then at slightly smaller breakpoints I have it so that only the nav and the large promo show, and then on mobile I have it so that only the nav shows.

The issue I'm having is that I can't get the height of the smaller promo banner on the right to match that of the main promo. I've tried adjusting the dimensions of the image placeholder so that it's not square (like it currently is) and no matter what I do it's either slightly shorter or slightly taller than the main promo. I need them to be the same height when both are in view.

Originally I had it setup so that the images stayed a static size and were just "cropped" as they shifted using

```
object-fit:cover;
```

but that doesn't work IE11 which unfortunately is a requirement (and is also not ideal since these images will be promo banners and parts would be getting cut off)....so that's why I'm trying to figure this way out to have them resize appropriately.

Here is a JSFiddle so you can see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/markb088/zpfbc7y3/5/

Here's the code from the JSFiddle in-case it becomes unavailable:

```css
html{
overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
body{
overflow-x: hidden;
background-color:#f3f3f3;
}

a.navLink{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:90%;
top:0px;
right:0px;
text-decoration:none;
z-index:10;
background-color:white;
opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

.menuContainer{
background-color: white;
border: 3px solid #d9d9d9;
/*height: 350px;*/
font-size: 0.8em;
font-weight: bold;
line-height:1.2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
 .columns{
 margin-left: 0.5rem;
 margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
}

.respImg{
/* height:350px;*/
width:100%;
/*object-fit: cover;*/
}

.imgHolder{
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

.navItem1, .navItem2, .navItem3{
position:relative;
/* height:110px;*/
padding-top:10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:631px){
 .regQuickNav{
   display:none;
  }
 .menuContainer{
  height: 125px; 
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:632px){
  .mobileQuickNav{
   display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<div class="columns" style="margin-left: 2rem; margin-right: 2rem; margin-top: 6px;">
<div class="column is-1-fullhd is-1-widescreen is-1-desktop is-2-tablet is-12-mobile is-flex-desktop-only is-flex-tablet-only">
<div class="menuContainer">
<div class="mobileQuickNav">
<div class="columns is-mobile " style="margin: 0 0 0 0;">
<div class="column">
<div style="position: relative;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://i.imgur.com/3COCw5x.png" alt="" width="100" height="70" />
<p style="text-align: center;">My Plan</p>
<a class="navLink" href="#">My Plan</a></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div style="position: relative;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://i.imgur.com/YWTV4pn.png" alt="" width="100" height="70" />
<p style="text-align: center;">Browse Courses</p>
<a class="navLink" href="#">Browse Courses</a></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div style="position: relative;"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://i.imgur.com/L07pkyt.png" alt="" width="100" height="70" />
<p style="text-align: center;">Events Calendar</p>
<a class="navLink" href="#">Events Calendar</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="regQuickNav">
<div class="columns" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;">
<div class="column is-full">
<div class="navItem1"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://i.imgur.com/3COCw5x.png" alt="" width="100" height="70" />
<p style="text-align: center;">My Plan</p>
<a class="navLink" href="#">My Plan</a></div>
<div class="navItem2"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://i.imgur.com/YWTV4pn.png" alt="" width="100" height="70" />
<p style="text-align: center;">Browse Courses</p>
<a class="navLink" href="#">Browse Courses</a></div>
<div class="navItem3"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://i.imgur.com/L07pkyt.png" alt="" width="100" height="70" />
<p style="text-align: center;">Events Calendar</p>
<a class="navLink" href="#">Events Calendar</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column is-8-fullhd column is-8-widescreen is-11-desktop is-10-tablet is-10-mobile is-hidden-mobile">
<div style="background-color: blue;  overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><img class="respImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/GH2QEuJ.png" /></div>
</div>
<div class="column is-3-fullhd column is-3-widescreen is-hidden-tablet-only is-hidden-desktop-only is-hidden-mobile">
<div style="background-color: red; overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: solid 1px #999999;"><img class="respImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/jqbRA3S.png" /></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

*Note that you'll need to expand the results panel and your browser wide enough so that the smaller promo banner shows. Majority of the CSS is included in the head tags of the html, due to the restrictions of the LMS.

I'm not overly familiar with grid systems, so not sure if I'm missing something to make it show with a matching height but still be responsive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to add the image as a background, you can use the following CSS:

```
.column {
background-size:cover;
}
```

It will also work with IE11.

The other option which will distort your image aspect ratio is to set a min-height value to the image:

```
.respImg {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: while I do have the option to add the image as a background, I've been asked to try to avoid having the images get cropped at all, and instead resize... the issue is that I need to retain the image aspect ratio to avoid it being distorted (the images will be promo banners with text, etc. so they need to be clear). Appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: How about changing the max-height of one of the images on each break point?